# Is there a way to drag/drop Outlook attachments into a web page (for upload)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, flash, outlook, activex

The users want this feature so badly they are actually OK with only using IE for this.  [From an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C), I cobbled together an ActiveX custom control in C# that I embedded into a web page and, functionally speaking, it works.  But aesthetically speaking, it's pretty bad with various versions of IE pestering users about "Allowing Blocked Content", warning them that it's dangerous, etc...

I tried doing this with Silverlight 5, but I ran into problems marshaling native memory (which is what Outlook attachment is stored in during drag/drop).  I've heard that Silverlight gave you limited access to the system, but seems too limited for this use case.  Unless I am missing something.

My last resort is Flash - of which I know nothing, but I don't want to get started if it's not even possible.  So, questions:

1. Is there a way to mark an ActiveX control safe so that it won't popup warnings? (Yes, it is strong  named already via the .NET's sn.exe applet).
2. Did I miss something with my Silverlight solution?  Can it be done?
3. Can I do this task in Flash?

Comment: Re #2: Were you able to get any kind of event to fire on drop from Outlook? SL locks down drag and drop eventing pretty tight, and won't allow an Outlook drop or access to the IDataObject before the drop event. Once you can get at the object, if you mark your app as requiring elevated trust, you can PInvoke to get the COM object, write that out to a temp folder, then work with a proper file.